# passing a parameter to a route from via a form submission in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to implement a search based on certain parameters. i have the view /home and that consists a form. I won't it to redirect to /edit-customer:/customerId view with customer id.

**HTML**,

```
<form>
From: <input type="text" name="customernumber"><br>

<a href="#/edit-customer/3">asdasd</a>
</form>
```

**route,**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        title: 'Customers',
        templateUrl: 'partials/customers.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl'
      })
      .when('/edit-customer/:customerID', {
        title: 'Edit Customers',
        templateUrl: 'partials/edit-customer.html',
        controller: 'editCtrl',
        resolve: {
          customer: function(services, $route){
            var customerID = $route.current.params.customerID;
            return services.getCustomer(customerID);
          }
        }
      }).when('/home',{
        title: 'home',
        templateUrl:'partials/home.html',
      }).when('/results',{
        title: 'search results',
        templateUrl: 'partials/results.html',
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
}]);
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand you are looking for, note ng-model directive on input element

```
<form>
From: <input type="text" ng-model="customerId" name="customernumber"><br>

<a href="#/edit-customer/{{customerId}}">asdasd</a>
</form>
```